# WCF Data Services and Entity Framework

Tags: wcf-data-services

just a couple of questions?

- Is WCF Data Services tightly integrated with EF
- Can we have WCF Data Services with our own data contracts (custom classes)? Any links to samples?
- If I implement WCF Data Services with custom classes (without using EF), does the methodology support oData standard?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF Data Service will happily serve up data from any data source, as long as it implements the `IQueryable` interface (and possible `IUpdateable` if you want to be able to update your existing data, too).

It's definitely **not** tied to EF only - you can use Linq-to-SQL or create your own custom provider for it - no problem.

Read up on MSDN's documentation on [Data Services Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd672591.aspx) for a start.

The main page on MSDN on WCF Data Services can be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx).